# Override the encoding of a single-file generated from a Django template (not an HTML file) in order to {% ssi %} include parts in latin1?

Tags: python, django, templates, python-3.x, character-encoding

I have a single template that needs to be encoded in `latin1` (to be stored in a file that has to be transmitted to a legacy system), whereas all other templates should render HTML pages in `utf-8`. The template includes, trough `{% ssi %}` tags, some dynamic documents that come from the legacy system and that are encoded in `latin1`.

If I try to include that documents I get the following error ([here is the complete traceback](http://pastebin.com/fifNdAR0)):

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 6426: invalid continuation byte
```

because of a `é` char in the legacy included file.

What I've tried so far:

1. I'm aware of [`FILE_CHARSET`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#file-charset) setting to change the encoding, but this
   changes all HTML and SQL encodings and this is not a viable
   solution.
2. I've checked [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Template) but it seems that I cannot set either
   Template or Context encoding on a per-file basis, they are all
   assumed to be '`utf-8`' or whatever `FILE_CHARSET` is.
3. Searched Google & SO for ideas. No luck.
4. I may convert the encoding later, eventually, but the error raises inside `Template.render()` so I've have to solve it on template loading, I think

Do a proper way to do that exists?

my config is: Python 3.4, Django 1.8.

Comment: Django 1.8, introduced the `charset` and `using` parameters to the TemplateResponse classes. Could they be useful in this case? See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/template-response/

Comment: @Pynchia I'm not generating a response, I'm saving the results of `render()` in a binary file but I'll investigate the internals of TemplateResponse in order to see if they encode the render results or if they pass the encoding to the Template somehow. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: unfortunately it seems that the encoding is forced after the template rendering phase has took place. So in my case this approach will not avoid the Exception.

Comment: here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/ , it says "[Render] Combines a given template with a given context dictionary and returns an HttpResponse object with that rendered text. ......  Django does not provide a shortcut function which returns a TemplateResponse because the constructor of TemplateResponse offers the same level of convenience as render()". Render has a `using` parameter, but lacks `charset`

Comment: I think you could write a Template backend which is exactly like the default one, but ignores FILE_CHARSET and uses 'latin1' instead. Then specify that explicit backend to render() for the incriminated page only. I've never tried it myself, dunno if subclassing a few classes would do. See `Custom backends` on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/templates/

Comment: I'll try. It's a good idea and should work! Thanks